# Is hydrostatics the appropriate tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I just do not know where to write this remark. Apologies if this is the wrong place. Also I do not know whether the discussions about tag creation are available. I did not find the one about [hydrostatics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydrostatics).

Is it reasonable to have a specialized tag, when a more general tag is missing. What I mean is that there is no tag covering *fluid statics* which might include both *hydrostatics* (a bad name, since there is more than water to it ...) and statics of gas.

The tag "statics" is not appropriate to fill the gap, given its definition.

Comment: I assume the reason [tag:statics] doesn't work for you is the "system of bodies" part?

Comment: Yes, it is the "system of bodies" parts. And I think (unless corrected) that it is a standard meaning for it. Also, there is _fluid dynamics_. I have seen a question tagged _fluid dynamics_, though it was about the statics of gas. The other point is that _hydrostatics_ does not seem so overused that it cannot be replaced by the more general _fluid statics_. But I do not know the discussions that decided its creation.

Comment: FWIW, the term *hydrodynamics* is often used to describe incompressible fluid dynamics, whether liquid or gas, so I guess the same idea could be extrapolated to [tag:hydrostatics].

Comment: I do not mind that. So _hydrostatics_ can cover the statics of all incompressible fluids. But I am concerned with the statics of compressible fluids. So I was suggesting _fluid statics_ to cover all, since _hydrostatics_ has the "incompressible" connotation.

Comment: [meta-tag:feature-request]? No, I think it should be [meta-tag:support].  [tag:fluid-mechanics] is enough. Why do you want it to be more special than that (assuming that's what you're trying to convey)? .

Comment: @babou I have no problem with the creation of [tag:fluid-statics] once there is a question that deals with it of course. If you write such a question and need the tag, just leave a comment and somebody will create it for you.

Comment: @Dimension I looked carefully at the tags comments. I did not choose support because I
did not need help. I considered the choice of tags one of the very
few features under user control. The tag _fluid-mechanics_ might do,
though it would be used only for "complessible fluid statics" since
all other sub-categories have their own tag. As it stand, this tag
does not show up when I type "fluid"or "mechanics". As it is, the
classification is messy. But I will not fight if that is what is
liked.
As for a question that would justify _fluid_statics_ : http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71355/

Comment: @babou: Oops, I meant [meta-tag:discussion], but as for so many subcategories, there aren't that many [tag:fluid-mechanics] questions... So I would go for merging [tag:fluid-dynamics] and [tag:fluid-statics] into [tag:fluid-mechanics].  Of course, two tags [tag:fluid-dynamics] and [tag:fluid-statics] is fine too, but they're a bit similar. (But [tag:hydrostatics] isn't that good, since  it is a rarely-used, almost obselote term.) .

Comment: @Dimension10 A unique tag _fluid-mechanics_ covering everything about fluids
statics and dynamics would be fine, as far as I am concerned. What
bothered me was that there was no tag for the question 71355, and the
imbalance on the tagging scheme, the loss of existing symetries, to
state it pedantically. Actually, why not use compositionality of tags
and have 2 tags _statics_ and _dynamics_ also.  The only problem is
that _statics_ is already taken with a different meaning.  Anyway,
_fluid-mechanics_ suits me well.

Comment: @babou: You're right, I guess... .   Wonder why nobody +1ed this yet? ...